# Show text near container

Tags: flutter

I am making this app in flutter and I want to position my text near the container and at this moment the text show up only under it. ( the grey container). The text I want to be positioned to the right of that container. Any idea?

```
   SingleChildScrollView(
               
               scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
               child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 children: [
                 

                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                             width: 340,
                             height: 120,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                             decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white,borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                             child: Column(
                               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                               children: [
                                 Container(
                                 width: 60,height: 60,
                                 margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                 decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey,borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                 
                                 ),
                                  Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 0, right: 10, left: 10),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                               children: [
                                 Text('Friends',textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
                               ], 
                                 )
 ]))
                               ],
                               
                             ),
                             
                         ),
                      
                      ],
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

````
                 
                 scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                 child: Container(
                      width: 340,
                      height: 120,
                     margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white,borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                          width: 60,height: 60,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey,borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                          
                          ),
                           Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 0, right: 10, left: 10),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text('Friends',textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
                        ], 
                          )
 ]))
                        ],
                        
                      ),
                      
                  )),```
````

Answer (score -1):

There's a few ways to do this, you can either use a stack instead of a column and manually position your widgets inside it by wrapping them with Align or Positioned, or replace your column for a Wrap and handle the spacing between your widgets yourself. Since you provided no visual representation of what exactly you're trying to achieve, I can't tell you which one is best for you, so I guess you'll have try both and find out which option works better.